# get the elementwise min/max in torch

Tags: lua, torch, tensor

I have a 2 cuda tensors and would like to get the minimum between them.

```
a=torch.randn(3, 3)
b=torch.randn(3, 3)
c=torch.min(a,b)
```

invalid arguments: DoubleTensor DoubleTensor 
expected arguments: DoubleTensor | [*DoubleTensor*] [*LongTensor*] DoubleTensor index

Now I would like to get a 3 by 3 matrix with the minimum of a and b (ideally in a way that also works with cuda tensors).

Anybody know how to fix this, I looked at 
http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.max

specifically the line  `torch.max(input, other, out=None) → Tensor`
which suggests that this should work by just providing the two tensors but as above that trows an error.

This is in torch-cl(distro-cl) running on ubuntu 17.04

Comment: This question clearly has nothing to do with CUDA programming. So why tag spam as one?

Comment: @talonmies because I want my answer to also work on cuda tensors.

Comment: CUDA doesn't have tensors.

Comment: @talonmies cuda tensors are what torch uses in order to control CUDA. So this is about torch using CUDA to get stuff done. So in this example in order to get a cuda tensor all you would need to do is call a:cuda() and then you have a cuda tensor instead.

Comment: I am not sure how many more times I am going to have repeat this. You are talking about features of Torch. They are not features of CUDA. And this question is not about features of CUDA and should not have been tagged as a CUDA quesiton

Answer (score 1):

The function computing the maximum (res. minimum) of each pair of values is `cmax` (resp. `cmin`).

Try

```
c = torch.cmin(a,b)
```

For further information have a look at the documentation https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#res-torchcmaxres-tensor1-tensor2.

It should also work with CudaTensors.